# Python gTTS, is there a way to change the speed of the speech

Tags: python, gtts

It seems that on gTTS there is no option for changing the speech of the text-to-speech apart from the slow argument.

I would like to speed up the sound by 5%. Any suggestion on how I can do it?

Best.

```
tts_de = gTTS("Hallo, guten tag.", lang = 'de')
tts_de.save("s.mp3")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't actually possible. According to the [offical gTTS docs](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/gtts/latest/gtts.pdf), the only arguments relating to speed gTTS accepts is `slow`, a boolean specifying whether or not to slow down the playback.

If you're playing the file through Python, however, I'm sure there is a module that supports sped-up playback.

Answer (score 4):

## Ubuntu + Python + gTTS

1}  Install sox

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install sox
$ sudo apt-get install libsox-fmt-all
```

2}  use the `tempo 1.9` option in `sox` to play gTTS output 1.9 times faster

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.5

from gtts import gTTS
import os 

mytext='hello'

language = 'en'
myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False)
myobj.save(mytext+".mp3")
os.system("play " + mytext + ".mp3"+" tempo 1.9")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pydub package to speed up your audio.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

audio = AudioSegment.from_file("test.mp3", format="mp3")
# or
audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3("test.mp3")
        
audio.speedup(playback_speed=2.0) # speed up by 2x
    
# export to mp3
final.export("final.mp3", format="mp3")
```