# How to use gtts library to read a text file?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am creating a quiz game using Tkinter. I want to use gtts to read a text file which contains question and options. So is there any way to do that? I tried using pyttsx3 but the voice is too robotic and it always says "*backslash n*" after the end of sentence (basically its a new line). 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to replace \n or any other character by space .here abc.txt is your text file

```
    from gtts import gTTS 
    import os
    file = open("abc.txt", "r").read().replace("\n", " ")
    speech = gTTS(text = str(file),lang='en',slow = False)
    speech.save("voice.mp3")
    os.system("start voice.mp3")
```

hope it solves your query. [here](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues/31) you can read more

Comment: Thank You! That helps. Any chance that I can reduce the speed of the voice??

Comment: @HarshR i think there is no functionality to change speed of voice. only bool values :slow or fast . further reading : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178646/python-gtts-is-there-a-way-to-change-the-speed-of-the-speech